# How to find whether the term is first or last in a vocabulary?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am using a vocabulary to get the list of terms in it. The tids for the terms are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I have no hierarchy in my taxonomy. Now I would like to find whether 1 is the first term in the vocabulary, similarly to find whether 5 is the last term in the vocabulary.

Is there any API way of doing this?

Comment: But first counting how? Vocabularies are tree, so do you mean first in own branch & depth, or first overall, aka first with no depth at all?

Comment: I have no hierarchy in my taxonomy. The only things that makes the difference between the terms is the weight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to obtain one level of your taxonomy terms. Use either [`taxonomy_get_tree($vid, 0, 1);`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) for top level ones, or [`taxonomy_get_children($tid)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/7) for children of a known element.

It should be sorted the way you want it, as both functions contain this in their code:

```
$query->orderBy('t.weight');
$query->orderBy('t.name');
```

Now you can use standard PHP functions [`reset(array &$array)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [`end(array &$array)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) to get first and last object from that array for comparison. Note that this will move internal pointer around, so don't use them lightly on arrays you also use elsewhere already.